# Why can I directly access my JSP?

Tags: google-app-engine, jsp

Resource/Static configuration in my google-app-engine.xml...

```
    <resource-files>
    <include path="/data/**" />
</resource-files>
<static-files>
    <include path="/images/**" />
    <include path="/bootstrap/**" />
    <include path="/views/error/*.html" />
    <include path="/favicon.ico" />
</static-files>
```

[image: Directory view of my project..]

By using `http://localhost:8080/views/SetNewPassword.jsp` I can directly access the JSP. With my current configuration, shouldn't this be hidden?

(Using maven setup with the local test/dev server for google app engine)

Comment: what are you actually trying to do? what purpose would you have for hiding JSP files? and why wouldn't simply requiring login and checking the session at the top of each JSP be sufficient?

Comment: Because there's usually a simple XML configuration solution for most things in GAE. Static/Resource mapping shows this. The functionality of SetNewPassword.jsp requires a token and is no "true" security concern, but I just wanted to tighten things up easily if possible.

Thanks for your suggestion though, I was leaning towards making sure a token existed when the JSP was loaded. 

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jsp's under WEB-INF folder are protected from direct access. Your jsp 'SetNewPassword.jsp' is not under 'WEB-INF' so I would imagine it to be directly accessible unless I am missing something.

Answer (score 1):

Because JSPs are not static files. They're compiled to servlets and executed at server side.

Quote from [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig?hl=en#Java_appengine_web_xml_Static_files_and_resource_files):

> Many web applications have files that are served directly to the user's browser, such as images, CSS style sheets, or browser JavaScript code. These are known as static files because they do not change, and can benefit from web servers dedicated just to static content. App Engine serves static files from dedicated servers and caches that are separate from the application servers.
>
> Files that are accessible by the application code using the filesystem are called resource files. These files are stored on the application servers with the app.
>
> By default, all files in the WAR are treated as both static files and resource files, except for JSP files, which are compiled into servlet classes and mapped to URL paths, and files in the WEB-INF/ directory, which are never served as static files and always available to the app as resource files.

Comment: Correct. So I should be able to have a certain mapping which points to a controller which then returns the compiled/rendered JSP, right?

The main goal is that one want one point of entry for the JSP..

"except for JSP files, which are compiled into servlet classes and mapped to URL paths"

In this case, do I control what the URL Paths they are mapped to? Can I disable this functionality?

Comment: You can put them under WEB-INF so that they aren't accessible directly, but only by a controller.